# Linq select with regex

Tags: c#, regex, linq

I want to extract the strings like `aaa.a1` and `aaa.a2` from my list. All this strings contain `"aaa."`.

How can I combine Regex with Linq?

```
var inputList = new List<string>() { "bbb aaa.a1 bbb", "ccc aaa.a2 ccc" };

var result = inputList.Where(x => x.Contains(@"aaa.")).Select(x => x ???? ).ToList();
```

Comment: is the length fixed? or is there always a space behind it?

Comment: No its is variable. But there is always a space.

Comment: from your example it looks like there is always a space before and after it so why not use string.split(" ") and check if any substring contains "aaa"

Comment: I need regex for further extraction reasons.

Comment: `aaa.a1` and `aaa.a2` are at same place in each string?

Comment: @PrasadTelkikar No.

Comment: Let me know if you have any doubts regarding my solution. I think you cannot rely on `.Where(x => x.Contains(@"aaa."))` because this checks for `aaa.` in any context while it makes sense here to check for a word boundary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use

```
var inputList = new List<string>() { "bbb aaa.a1 bbb", "ccc aaa.a2 ccc" };
var result = inputList
    .Select(i => Regex.Match(i, @"\baaa\.\S+")?.Value)
    .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))
    .ToList();
foreach (var s in result)
    Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output:

```
aaa.a1
aaa.a2
```

See [C# demo](https://ideone.com/NMShNI)

The `Regex.Match(i, @"\baaa\.\S+")?.Value` part tries to match the following pattern in each item:

- `\b` - a word boundary
- `aaa\.` - an `aaa.` substring
- `\S+` - 1+ non-whitespace chars.

The `.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x))` will discard empty items that result from the items with no matching strings.

Answer (score 2):

You could try slight different solution:

```
var result = inputList
  .Where(i => Regex.Match(i, @"\baaa\.[a-z0-9]+")?.Success)
  // or even
  // .Where(i => Regex.Match(i, @"\ba+\.[a-z0-9]+")?.Success)
```

Comment: I like your solution too. :D